# How to combine time-series based features with different frequencies

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I have 3 features which I want to use in my classifier. They are all time-series data-based. However, they are all at different frequencies and there have different matrix dimensions. I was wondering if someone could give me some pointers on how to combine these three features?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: there are tools to increase the frequency using statistical tools

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @ChuckKillerDoll, you could find aggregate / derive features from your current measures, but chances are you will lose information by doing so. Another way to go about it, is to create three separate models and train a model for each of the frequency information matrices individually. These produce output scores $S_1,S_2,S_3$, you can then combine these in a new ensemble model. The easiest way to combine them is in a linear model:

$$S = a_1 S_1 + a_2 S_2 + a_3 S_3$$

Here $S$ is the final output score and you still need to learn the weights $a_i$ on a validation set. You could of course, plug the scores into more complicated models ... The main disadvantage of this technique is that you lose some of the covariance information.

Answer (score 2):

I would try an state-space model. The simplest possible form would be:
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{pmatrix} \theta_{1t} \\ \theta_{2t} \\ \theta_{3t}
\end{pmatrix} &=& \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & I & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & I \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\theta_{1,t-1} \\ \theta_{2,t-1} \\ \theta_{3,t-1}
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} \eta_{1t} \\ \eta_{2t} \\ \eta_{3t}
\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}Y_{1t} \\ Y_{2t} \\ Y_{3t}
\end{pmatrix} &=& \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & I & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & I \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \theta_{1t} \\ \theta_{2t} \\ \theta_{3t}
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} \epsilon_{1t} \\ \epsilon_{2t} \\ \epsilon_{3t}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
where all the $Y_{it}$, $\theta_{it}$ etc. are to be understood as vectors of the same dimensions of your three time series.

You can fit such model --a multivariate random walk plus noise-- even if not all the $Y$'s are observed at all times, and estimate the state vector at all possible $t$'s. This removes the problem of the different frequencies of the three time series.

If the situation warrants, you might also fit a different model. For instance, if there is some redundancy among the components of $Y_{it}$ you might want to use $\theta_{it}$ with $dim(\theta_{it}) < dim(Y_{it})$, and fit what would be essentially a dynamic factor analysis model.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your problem is related to *"feature engineering"*.

Dealing with financial market time series, I use to create one new column (feature) for each *set of parameters* of each indicator.
For example a simple moving average (SMA) is defined by the `set = {LookbackPeriod,Frequency,ShortPeriod,LongPeriod}` and each combination of these elements forms a new feature/attribute.

The instances of your Y values (classes) can be trained separately (in your classifier) for each frequency, like Return(t+period) where `period == days, weeks, ...`

If you want something more general you are trying to predict using ["first-order rule learning"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Order_Inductive_Learner)